# sending javascript 'this' to rails 'create.js.erb'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to use `remote true` to perform an ajax submission to a controller, which will run a create action, then on ajax success, perform some javascript to delete the row.

This seems pretty simple, but rails is making it difficult.

My set up ended like this:

FORM

```
= form_tag modifications_url, class: "inline", remote: true do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :id, modification.model.id
  = submit_button "Reject", class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

Modifications_Controller

```
class ModificationsController < NestedController
  belongs_to :app_group, :app, :organization
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @modifications = ModificationDecorator.decorate(get_modifications).group_by(&:what_was_modified)
  end

  def create
    @modification = Modification.find(params[:id])
    authorize!(:approve, @modification)
    if params[:resolution] == 'accept' 
      result = @modification.accept(current_user, params[:reason])
    elsif params[:resolution] == 'reject' 
      result = @modification.reject(current_user, params[:reason])
    end
  end
```

Now - according to the documentation I was reading, by placing a .js.erb file within the modification view folder with the same name as the action (create), It should run that code following a successful ajax call.

So in my `create.js.erb` file I tried an alert

`alert('testing')` which runs when I hit my submit button! YAY!

But, when I swap out the alert for `console.log($(this))` I get some wild results like `window` and other things that dont reference the css classes clicked.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(this)` is localized, when you bounce to the server and to a new page it's lost.  If you need to keep it you can either create your own ajax call to create where you do something with it or pass it in as params to use it in UJS

Comment: i see. thanks.  I'm still trying to understand rails ajax magic...coming to terms though.